# Is there a way to view commands run in the background in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, java-me, background

I use Eclipse Helios for developing J2ME applications. I wanted to know if there was a way I could see the background/text-line commands that are executed for each click/action on the GUI (eg. Compile, Run, Creating a J2ME package). I am interested in it so I can run through the process using a script.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing specific that you can do to see all commands run in Eclipse.  First, there is no one to one mapping between code being executed in Eclipse and java commands that you might run from the command line.  So, even though you might be able to view individual commands in vim or Emacs, you won't be able to do this Eclipse.

However, there are some things that may help.  There is a platform tracing facility that will print some trace messages to stdout.  However, this is not widely used outside of core Eclipse projects so you won't be able to get full tracing on all commands.  Also, this facility is not meant to be a general tracing facility, but really only for a few plugins that you are interested in.  You can find more information about it here:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_use_the_platform_debug_tracing_facility%3F

So, you will need to create a `.options` file in your Eclipse install directory with something like the following contents:

```
org.eclipse.platform/debug=true
org.eclipse.ui/debug=true
org.eclipse.core.runtime/debug=true
org.eclipse.core.resources/debug=true
org.eclipse.core.commands/debug=true
org.eclipse.core.filesystem/debug=true
org.eclipse.core.jobs/debug=true
```

These are a few of the low-level Eclipse plugins that will very likely contain some tracing information.  However, without knowing more about what you are trying to do, it is hard to recommend specific plugins to trace.

Comment: I mostly use vim for writing code and write my own makefiles. I have just started to use Eclipse (IDE) and find everything done for me. It would be great if I could "see" what gets invoked where so as to get a better handle/greater control over the project.